# CASE Expression with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I am using:

```
SELECT
  CASE SR.[ContainerId] WHEN SR.[ContainerId] IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS [IsSampleReceived]
FROM SomeTable SR where SomeCondition
```

Its not giving me the desired result. `IsSampleReceived` is always `1`. I don't know why, maybe there's some thing wrong in `WHEN SR.[ContainerId] IS NULL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two formats of using `CASE` and you are mixing them together.

> The CASE expression has two formats:
>
> The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple
>   expressions to determine the result.
>
> The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions to
>   determine the result.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Instead, try:

```
select case 
        when SR.[ContainerId] is null
            then 0
        else 1
        end as [IsSampleReceived]
from SomeTable SR
where SomeCondition
```

Answer (score 3):

Nearly! You were mixing the two different syntax forms:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SR.[ContainerId] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [IsSampleReceived]
FROM SomeTable SR where SomeCondition
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of CASE statements: "simple" and "searched". In your code, you are combining these two kinds of statements, and that is giving you incorrect results.

Simple:

```
SELECT CASE SR.[ContainerId] WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [IsSampleReceived]
FROM SomeTable SR where SomeCondition
```

Searched:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SR.[ContainerId] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [IsSampleReceived]
FROM SomeTable SR where SomeCondition
```

In your original query, it is doing a simple version comparing the value of SR.[ContainerId] to the value of `SR.[ContainerId] IS NULL`. The result of that comparison will always be false, so the else condition was always selected.